# Почему не срабатывает скрипт? Что я делаю не так?

Tags: javascript

Что я делаю не так, почему скрипт не срабатывает?

Дана кнопка. По нажатию на эту кнопку сформируйте таблицу table размером 5 на 5 и выведите ее на экран.

```html
        <input type="button" value="table" id="input">
        
        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById('input');
            button.addEventListener('click', func);
            
            
            
            function func(){
                var parent = button.parentElement;
                var table = document.createElement('table');
                
                for(var i =1; i<=5 i++){
                    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    for(var j = 1; j<=5; j++){
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.innerHTML = 'ячейка- ' + j;
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                }
            parent.appendChild(table);
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отладкой воспользуйся. Хотя тебе даже IDE должна такую ошибку подсветить:

> [image: скриншот]

А ещё ты `tbody` не создала.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79740/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy---------).

Answer (score 1):

i<=5  точку с запятой " ; " забыли в цикле for

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/273581)

Comment: @KostaB., а если подумать?

Comment: @Qwertiy и к бабке не ходи. =) что мешает Копировать код в ответ и внести поправку?